# GitHub from Visual Studio 2013 - Authorization Required

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-2013

I've been working on a project and storing my files in my own GitHub account so when I go from work to home and vise versa I can easily have my files up-to-date.

I am using Team Explorer through Visual Studio 2013 - same versions at home and at work.  When at home everything works fine, I can Sync in the changes I've made at work and then when I'm finished I can commit changes back up without a worry.

Here is my problem.  At work I can sync changes made from home but when I got to commit changes back to GitHub I get a 401 (Authorization Required).

[image]

I know that at home, at some stage, I had a windows authentication popup window that asked for my GitHub credentials, which makes sense as to why it is working at home.  However, this has never happened at work and I do not know how to authenticate manually.

My current work around is to run the git commits from the command line, but it would be nice to be able to do it straight from VS.

Comment: If you go to Start -> Credential Manager (you need to type this in), can you see the credentials you use to log in to GitHub mentioned there?

Comment: I've checked there too, Web Credentials shows nothing and Windows Credentials has no mention of GitHub (on work computer). I can check home computer later when I am home.

Comment: Do you have two factor authentication turned on? Have a read through this: http://blog.krisvandermast.com/GithubAndVisualStudioAndTwoFactorAuthentication.aspx. It's extended, but he has encountered the same error. I doubt the problem is an incorrect password or you wouldn't have been able to sync the changes you made at home.

Comment: Just checked Two-factor authentication is off.  Thanks for the article.  The strange this is, from that article, when he presses the sync button he gets a `Windows Security` popup, I don't get that. It just says the error message I posted in the question.  I have got the `Windows Security` popup on the home computer however.

Comment: So, did this solve your issue? About the pop up, you might have clicked the option to 'Remember credentials' in the pop up.

Comment: No it doesn't because I don't get the pop up at all.

Comment: I meant the very first time, possibly when you established the connection to GitHub. You could probably go to 'Settings' and change this. If nothing else, you could try re-establishing the connection to GitHub from work. Are you still getting the '401' problem though?